# ASP.net - open and close a list on button click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am pretty advanced in C# but a newcomer in the world of ASP.NET.

My HomeController.cs:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // tuple -> item1 = key string / item2 = assigned list
    var configList = new List<Tuple<string, List<string>>>();
    configList = fillItWithSomeData(..)
    ViewBag.ConfigSettings = configList;

    return View();
}
```

My Index.cshtml:

```
<div>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var elements in ViewBag.configSettings)
        {
            <div class="col-md-8 checkbox">
                /*I NEED A BUTTON HERE*/
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">@elements.Item1
                </label>
            </div>
            foreach (var listElement in elements.Item2)
            {
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 checkbox">
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox">@listElement
                    </label>
                </div>
            }
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Every key string in my list contains a list of strings. (look at var configList)
In my view I want to have a button for each key string which should be able to open or close the assigned list of the respective key string. I currently use ASP.NET-MVC. How can I program that? In C# or do I need to use JS for that? I really have no idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need javascript if you want to respond to client side events. But its a bit unclear what you trying to do.

Comment: Summarized: Something like a dropdownlist... I want to have some key strings. Every key string contains a button on the left side... My purpose is to open the whole list of the respective key string on button click or close the list if the list is already open.

Comment: Do you mean something like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s7gnokgy/)?

Comment: thats exactly what I mean Stephen!!

Comment: Just with a button instead of a checkbox.... It is easy with a static XML tree... but in my upper example there can be 1 - n key-Strings with 1 - n elements... look at the "foreach{foreach{..}}"

Comment: Then just add a button and handle the click even of the button instead of the checkbox. But its hard to understand what your really wanting to do with this, especially with that horrible use of `Tuple` (use a view model!). And what is the point of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap Accordion or bootstrap Collapsible panel.
below code using bootstrap Collapsible panel.

```
<div>
<div class="row">
    @foreach (var elements in ViewBag.configSettings)
    {
        <div class="col-md-8 checkbox">
            /*I NEED A BUTTON HERE*/
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#@elements.Item1">@elements.Item1
            </label>
        </div>
        foreach (var listElement in elements.Item2)
        {
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 checkbox collapse" id="@elements.Item1">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox">@listElement
                </label>
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>
```